# What would you like from MetroSE?

Tags: discussion

[MetroSE](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-US/app/metrose/9afeac7b-f68e-4c10-ae34-4127ef38b197) is an application that I worked on for the Stack Overflow contest [apptivate.ms](http://apptivate.ms/apps/28/metrose).  Now that it's been a few weeks, I'm looking to get feedback on the current version and any other features that you'd like to have.

Basically what I'm looking to do is collect a list of bugs, feature requests, and anything else into a list of requirements for v2.0.  I plan on doing a total re-design/re-work of the entire project since now I have a little more time, and resources to work on this in greater detail.

If you want to report an official bug you can [do so here](https://kronoskoders.fogbugz.com/default.asp?pg=pgPublicEdit).  And see it's [status here](https://kronoskoders.fogbugz.com/default.asp?pg=pgPublicViewForm) as well.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Two words: write support.

Comment: better background, caching of fetched data, accessible notifications from within the app

Comment: @allquixotic Two words: API limitations.

Comment: @Bob actually, there is write support in the new 2.1 API, but currently only for comments. Write support for questions/answers will happen eventually, but it may be a while.

Comment: Shouldn't you make a bug tracker, and if you have one, give a link?

Comment: @CamiloMartin Totally forgot to add that.

Comment: @Sathya what do you mean by "Accessible notifications"

Comment: Doh! I really shouldn't try and answer questions late at night - I misread it sorry. I've got Windows 8 on the brain. Time to delete my daft answers. It is the "Modern UI" (what was called "Metro") that I want to go away, not your app.

Comment: @JulianKnight no problem.  Just making sure that my app wasn't causing any big probs ^__^